# TypeScript: implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to move a custom hook I use in Vue to handle i18n from JavaScript to TypeScript, but I keep getting the following error:

> `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Languages'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Languages'.`

[image: This is the code]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Then I could copy the code myself and check the types at various spots without having to retype it all from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Languages` is typed as `{ en: object }`, but I suspect you want it to be a string dictionary, which can be typed like this:

```js
type Languages = {
  [locale: string]: Record<string, string>;
}
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5IgZygXigbwCgoSoBtAGwHsBjOCiALik2ACcBLZAXWYCUINKmwAmAHladkAGhbsuSAHwBuQgF9ChUJCgcAjAA4EAYSoIAZhyQAVcNDxFSUanQbNJC1U4C2WTOixmeGQ0DExVDUIhBFYoGjYIOGAIAElDBFwoAApoyyRmfSNTCytbSABKXEVsx1IXeiYoAHIm6WJSX0x-MOZcqwA6Tu6sNqdgAH0sgGsIEHd5ZErapxIE4BQ2DOAACw5MQb8AzDIdvf76hm4yGZBuL1INNXKgA)